# Getting PNG images drawn to canvas using image's Alpha channel

Tags: delphi, canvas, png

I'm making a program to show lottery draw results history and statistics from the result data.  I want to show images of the balls instead of just their numbers, so I made a set of png images of 3D-looking balls with numbers on them, small ones 32x32 and larger 48x48. Such as:

[image: Image of a lottery ball]

These are obviously circular with anti-aliased edges even on the alpha channel. I couldn't get them loaded into a TImageList and shown on a canvas without loosing alpha transparency, the best I got was a hard mask. Instead I have created at design-time a TImage for each ball with the the ball's png image loaded. To easily reference to them by ball number I declared `var Balls: array[1..59] of TImage;`, which I connect to each TImage in my form's OnCreate which is simply `Balls[1] := Image01; Balls[2] := Image02;` and so on.  I use the OnMouseEnter/OnMouseLeave/OnClick events of these TImages to highlight and select them. I actually have another TImage to represent the selection highlight which is slightly larger than the balls and appears behind a Ball's TImage when the mouse is over a ball.  All this works fine, but now I want to use the same images in a TDrawGrid which displays all the results data mostly as text but I want the ball numbers shown as images, using the OnDrawCell event.

Here's the problem: I can't find a way to copy the image with it's alphachannel onto the DrawGrid canvas - I had the error message when using CopyRect: 'can only modify an image if it contains a bitmap' so I found the solution online to create a TBitmap and copy the Ball's TImage but it lost the alpha blend and the background is black. I just want to be able to copy an alphachannel image to any canvas where the background could be any colour (clBtnFace for instance).

```
const
  CellPadding = 4;
  Colnames: array [0..15] of string = ('Draw','Day','Date','Month','Year','1st','2nd','3rd','4th','5th','6th','B','Jackpot','Wins','Machine','Ball set');

procedure TLottoResults.DrawGrid1DrawCell(Sender: TObject; ACol, ARow: Integer; Rect: TRect; State: TGridDrawState);
var
  dcBall: Integer;
  dcRect: TRect;
  dcBmp: TBitmap;
begin
  DrawGrid1.Canvas.Brush.Style := bsClear;
  if ARow = 0 then
  begin
    DrawGrid1.Canvas.Font.Name := 'Tahoma';
    DrawGrid1.Canvas.Font.Size := 12;
    DrawGrid1.Canvas.Font.Style := [fsBold];
    DrawGrid1.Canvas.TextRect(Rect, Rect.Left+CellPadding, Rect.Top,  Colnames[ACol])
  end
  else
  begin
    if gdSelected in State then DrawGrid1.Canvas.Brush.Color := clGreen
    else DrawGrid1.Canvas.Brush.Color := clNavy;
    DrawGrid1.Canvas.FillRect(Rect);
    DrawGrid1.Canvas.Font.Color := clWhite;
    if ACol in [5..11] then  // columns to display images instead of text
    begin
      // StringGrid1 is what the raw CSV data is loaded into first and is kept invisible,
      // and it's contents are copied to DrawGrid1 for actual display.
      if TryStrToInt(StringGrid1.Cells[ACol, ARow-1], dcBall)then
      begin
        if dcBall in [1..59] then
        begin
          dcBmp := TBitmap.Create;
//          Following disabled code is what has been tried in various combinations
//          dcBmp.PixelFormat := pf32bit;
//          dcBmp.TransparentMode := tmFixed;
//          dcBmp.TransparentColor := clBtnFace;
//          dcBmp.AlphaFormat := afDefined;
//          Balls[dcBall].Picture.Graphic.Transparent := True;
          dcBmp.Assign(Balls[dcBall].Picture.Graphic);
          Balls[dcBall].Picture.Bitmap := dcBmp;
//          FreeAndNil(dcBmp);

          dcRect := TRect.Create(0,0,32,32);
          if DataLoaded then
            DrawGrid1.Canvas.CopyRect(TRect.Create(Rect.Left+2, Rect.Top+2, Rect.Left+32+2, Rect.Top+32+2), Balls[dcBall].Canvas, dcRect);
//          DrawGrid1.Canvas.Draw(Rect.Top,Rect.Left,Balls[dcBall].Picture.Graphic); // Draw draws in the wrong place, why?
        end
        else
        begin // Display as text if not in range 1 to 59
          DrawGrid1.Canvas.Font.Name := 'Courier New';
          DrawGrid1.Canvas.Font.Size := 12;
          DrawGrid1.Canvas.Font.Style := [];
          DrawGrid1.Canvas.TextRect(Rect, Rect.Left+CellPadding, Rect.Top+(DrawGrid1.RowHeights[ARow] div 2)-(DrawGrid1.Canvas.TextHeight('Ag') div 2), '('+StringGrid1.Cells[ACol, ARow-1]+')');
        end;
      end
    else
    begin // Display as text is TryStrToInt failed
      DrawGrid1.Canvas.Font.Name := 'Courier New';
      DrawGrid1.Canvas.Font.Size := 12;
      DrawGrid1.Canvas.Font.Style := [];
      DrawGrid1.Canvas.TextRect(Rect, Rect.Left+CellPadding, Rect.Top+(DrawGrid1.RowHeights[ARow] div 2)-(DrawGrid1.Canvas.TextHeight('Ag') div 2), StringGrid1.Cells[ACol, ARow-1]);
    end;
    end
    else
    begin // All other columns display as text
      DrawGrid1.Canvas.Font.Name := 'Courier New';
      DrawGrid1.Canvas.Font.Size := 12;
      DrawGrid1.Canvas.Font.Style := [];
      DrawGrid1.Canvas.TextRect(Rect, Rect.Left+CellPadding, Rect.Top+(DrawGrid1.RowHeights[ARow] div 2)-(DrawGrid1.Canvas.TextHeight('Ag') div 2), StringGrid1.Cells[ACol, ARow-1]);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please, could you provide some code of your specific problem. That prove how far did you try and it will help other members to understand your problem better, at the time, you will give them a context of your issue. Please, check these links: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Is this for Delphi? If so, we should probably tag it as such

Comment: Delphi, XE8 but a solution that works for any version would be fine too!

Comment: Have you tried [TGraphic.Draw](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/Vcl.Graphics.TGraphic.Draw)

Comment: You're on the wrong track, return to loading them to an image list and use 'draw' as commented. Apart from 'AlphaBlend' GDI ignores alpha channel, 'CopyRect' won't work.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz I think I used Draw when I had them in an ImageList and I lost the alpha channel, I could only use the mask but it left a hard jagged edge around the edge of the circle.  Hmm... I will have to try the ImageList again to be double sure of what happened.  I think I will keep the image in the TImage's because I'm using the Mouse events on them on another tab...though I suppose I could copy the Imagelist images into all the TImages on startup? I deally I just want one copy of the images stored at design-time or held as resource and paint them wherever else they are wanted at run-time.

Answer (score 3):

UPDATE - I solved it myself.  I took another look at the Draw method I first tried (and abandoned because they were appearing in the wrong place) and realised I had muddled up the X+Y. Here's the cleaned up code. I'm sure it could be simplified a bit more. I'm still playing around to see how I can craft a nice DrawGrid. [Here's a screen grab of the result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpxfD.jpg)

```
procedure TLottoResults.DrawGrid1DrawCell(Sender: TObject; ACol, ARow: Integer; Rect: TRect; State: TGridDrawState);
var
  dcBall: Integer;
begin
  DrawGrid1.Canvas.Brush.Style := bsClear;
  if ARow = 0 then
  begin
    DrawGrid1.Canvas.Font.Name := 'Tahoma';
    DrawGrid1.Canvas.Font.Size := 12;
    DrawGrid1.Canvas.Font.Style := [fsBold];
    DrawGrid1.Canvas.TextRect(Rect, Rect.Left+CellPadding, Rect.Top, Colnames[ACol])
  end
  else
  begin
    if gdSelected in State then DrawGrid1.Canvas.Brush.Color := clGreen
    else DrawGrid1.Canvas.Brush.Color := clNavy;
    DrawGrid1.Canvas.FillRect(Rect);
    DrawGrid1.Canvas.Font.Color := clWhite;
    if ACol in [5..11] then  // columns to display images instead of text
    begin
      // StringGrid1 is what the raw CSV data is loaded into first and is kept invisible,
      // and it's contents are copied to DrawGrid1 for actual display.
      if TryStrToInt(StringGrid1.Cells[ACol, ARow-1], dcBall)then
      begin
        if dcBall in [1..59] then
        begin
          if DataLoaded then
             DrawGrid1.Canvas.Draw(Rect.Left+2,Rect.Top+2,Balls[dcBall].Picture.Graphic); 
        end
        else
        begin // Display as text if not in range 1 to 59
          DrawGrid1.Canvas.Font.Name := 'Courier New';
          DrawGrid1.Canvas.Font.Size := 12;
          DrawGrid1.Canvas.Font.Style := [];
          DrawGrid1.Canvas.TextRect(Rect, Rect.Left+CellPadding, Rect.Top+(DrawGrid1.RowHeights[ARow] div 2)-(DrawGrid1.Canvas.TextHeight('Ag') div 2), '('+StringGrid1.Cells[ACol, ARow-1]+')');
        end;
      end
      else
      begin // Display as text is TryStrToInt failed
        DrawGrid1.Canvas.Font.Name := 'Courier New';
        DrawGrid1.Canvas.Font.Size := 12;
        DrawGrid1.Canvas.Font.Style := [];
        DrawGrid1.Canvas.TextRect(Rect, Rect.Left+CellPadding, Rect.Top+(DrawGrid1.RowHeights[ARow] div 2)-(DrawGrid1.Canvas.TextHeight('Ag') div 2), StringGrid1.Cells[ACol, ARow-1]);
      end;
    end
    else
    begin // All other columns display as text
      DrawGrid1.Canvas.Font.Name := 'Courier New';
      DrawGrid1.Canvas.Font.Size := 12;
      DrawGrid1.Canvas.Font.Style := [];
      DrawGrid1.Canvas.TextRect(Rect, Rect.Left+CellPadding, Rect.Top+(DrawGrid1.RowHeights[ARow] div 2)-(DrawGrid1.Canvas.TextHeight('Ag') div 2), StringGrid1.Cells[ACol, ARow-1]);
    end;
  end;
end;
```